# Android JSONObject retrieve value

Tags: android, json

Hey here is the json response I'm getting
 {
    "status": 200,
    "message": "success"
 }
and this is the error I'm getting 
org.json.JSONException: No value for status
this is how I'm extracting the values

```
 try {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(dataSent);

                if(jObject.getInt("status") == 200){
                    isProfileCreated = true;
                    return isProfileCreated;
                }else{
                    isProfileCreated = false;
                    return isProfileCreated;
                }

    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

what could be causing this problem it crashes on this particular line

```
if(jObject.getInt("status") == 200){
```

Comment: Try `jObject.optInt("status",-1)` instead of `jObject.getInt("status")`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your json contains key "status":

```
 if (json.has("status")) {
// json contains "status" key
 }
```